Email Address Authentication for Gmail API Fails
I'm trying to make the GMail API work.  This is what I have:

A project in the Google Cloud for the Gmail API.
Valid client ID and client secret codes.
Valid redirect_uri
Valid test user
Redirect and callback php scripts.

On a configuration page, I have a link to authenticate the user.  When I click that link it goes to a Google account page to select the account, then runs the redirect script which gets a new authentication code.  It then passes that code to the callback script.  All the codes and links are correct.
Here is a test callback script (with private data removed):
<?php
// Enable error reporting for debugging
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Google OAuth credentials
$client_id = 'PRIVATE';
$client_secret = 'PRIVATE';
$redirect_uri = 'PRIVATE';

// Retrieve the authorization code from the URL parameters
$auth_code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : '';

if (empty($auth_code)) {
    die('Authorization code is missing.');
}

// Log the authorization code to verify it's correct
error_log("Authorization Code: " . $auth_code);

// Token URL for Google OAuth 2.0
$token_url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';

// Prepare the POST data for the token exchange
$post_data = http_build_query([
    'code' => $auth_code,
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
]);

// Initialize curl to make the POST request
$ch = curl_init();

// Set curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
]);

// Execute the curl request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for curl errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

// Close the curl session
curl_close($ch);

// Debugging: print raw response for clarity
error_log("Response from Google OAuth API: " . $response);

// Check if the response is empty
if (empty($response)) {
    die('Error: Empty response from Google OAuth API.');
}

// Decode the response JSON to check the result
$response_data = json_decode($response, true);

// Debugging: Print the decoded response to understand the structure
error_log("Decoded Response: " . print_r($response_data, true));

// Check if the response contains an access token
if (isset($response_data['access_token'])) {
    echo 'Access Token: ' . $response_data['access_token'];
} else {
    // If no access token is found, output the error message
    echo 'Error exchanging authorization code: ' . $response_data['error'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Error Description: ' . $response_data['error_description'];
}
?>

But when this script runs the curl command, this is the response data I get back:
Error exchanging authorization code: invalid_grant
Error Description: Bad Request

That isn't descriptive enough for me to figure out what's wrong.
Does anyone know how I might narrow down the failure?
I expect to get back an access_token and a refresh_token.

I don't know if this is a clue or not.  If I try to authenticate a Gmail address that is not on the user list for my project, Google tells me access is blocked.  This does indicate that the authenticate process is somewhat working.

Try and authenticate again get a new refresh token.

Thanks.  After continually hounding ChatGPTT and Gemini with hundreds of questions,  I found one problem.  White space causes the php script to fail.  I don't know if it was a blank line before .  Removed them both.  Also, for some unknown reason my script is being called twice, meaning your suggestion is accurate because the same auth token is used twice.  Don't know why the script is called twice, can't find it.  But trapped it out and now have refresh tokens.  On to the next problem...  Thanks!
